# Logging in to Magento account from Python script

Tags: python, magento, magento2

I'm trying to login to Magento account from Python script using requests module, the relevant code I made looks as below:

```
s = requests.session()
main_url = '<redacted.tld>/en/index.html'
html_data = s.get('https://'+main_url, headers=headers, timeout=(30, 30), verify=dst_verify_ssl)

web_user = 'test@test.com'
web_pass = '123test321'
form_key = soup.find('input', {'name':'form_key'})['value']
l_url = 'https://<redacted.tld>/'
l_route = 'en/customer/account/loginPost/'

login_payload = {
'form_key':form_key,
'login[username]':web_user,
'login[password]':web_pass
}

login_req = s.post(l_url + l_route, headers=headers, data=login_payload)
```

But it's not getting me logged in so I was wondering if someone could tell me what does it take to login via Python to the Magento account?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave this one a go on a public demo instance and I can see the data on the Magento 2 dashboard just fine:

```py
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    web_user = 'youremail@example.com'
    web_pass = 'yourpassword'
    
    s = requests.session()
    main_url = 'https://magento2demo/'
    html_data = s.get(main_url)
    form_soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data.content, 'html.parser')
    form_key = form_soup.find('input', {'name':'form_key'})['value']
    
    login_route = 'https://magento2demo/customer/account/loginPost/'
    login_payload = {
      'form_key': form_key,
      'login[username]': web_user,
      'login[password]': web_pass
    }
    
    login_req = s.post(login_route, data=login_payload)
    
    account_url = "https://magento2demo/customer/account/"
    html_account = s.get(account_url)
    account_soup =  BeautifulSoup(html_account.content, 'html.parser')
    
    info = account_soup.find('div', {'class':'box-information'}).find('div', {'class':'box-content'})
    assert web_user in str(info)
```

```
                "beautifulsoup4": { "version": "==4.9.3"
                "requests": { "version": "==2.26.0"
```

What's the response code on the POST? Anything peculiar in your headers?
Might wanna add more reproducible data if the above doesn't help.

Comment: thanks for your response but how can i do if I want to automate the password change for an account ?